# do...while scoping issue when initializing variables inside of body

Tags: javascript

Was having some fun with `prompt`, `parseInt` and `do...while` and just stumbled upon the following:

```
do {
    let length = prompt('Enter a number between 8 and 128 (inclusive) for your length.');
    length = parseInt(length, 10);
} while (length < 8 || length > 128);
```

Every time I would use the Chrome Developer tools to inspect the value of `length` during the `while` execution, I would see a value of `0`. I thought there was something up with the `radix` I had chosen for `parseInt` but that was not the case.

I noticed that VS Code was complaining that the `let length` was not being used anywhere. That was odd. Once I removed the variables outside of the loop and declared as separate `string` and `number` fields instead, (i.e., `let lengthPrompt` and `let length`), everything worked out:

```
let lengthPrompt;
let length;

do {
  lengthPrompt = prompt('Length?');
  length = parseInt(lengthPrompt, 10);
} while (length < 8 || length > 128);
```

Is this an issue with scope or some other weird JS specific thing I am unaware of.

Comment: `let` has block scope, so in your first code, `let` does not exist after the `}` of the `do`

Comment: yet `let` in `for(let x` is before `{` but is in scope only inside the body (not after the for loop) :p javascript inconsistent as ever